# Linking legend with data points in ggiraph

Tags: r, ggiraph

I'm trying to create a ggiraph plot that I would like to include in a rmarkdown document where hovering the legend will also highlight the corresponding points in the plot.

I've tried below code, but while I can hover the points in the plot and the legend they are not linked. Is there a way to link these?

```
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, data_id = Species)) +
  geom_point_interactive() +
  scale_color_brewer_interactive(palette = 'Set1',
                                 data_id = function(breaks) as.character(breaks))

p = girafe(ggobj = p)
p = girafe_options(p,
                   opts_hover(girafe_css("stroke:black;fill:black;")),
                   opts_hover_key(girafe_css("stroke:black;fill:black")))
print(p)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end, @Johan?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I did end up finding a solution, so I hope this works for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921572/3949200

Answer (score 0):

Using the information in @Sidders solution I was able to make this work:

```r
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, data_id = Species)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(`data-id` = Species), extra_interactive_params = "data-id") +
  scale_color_brewer_interactive(extra_interactive_params = "data-id",
                                 `data-id` = unique(iris$Species),
                                 palette = 'Set1',
                                 data_id = function(breaks) as.character(breaks))

p = girafe(ggobj = p)
p = girafe_options(p,
                   opts_hover(girafe_css("stroke:black;fill:black;")),
                   opts_hover_key(girafe_css("stroke:black;fill:black")))
print(p)
```